# Error in C++ Vector Usage: No matching member function for call to 'push_back'

Tags: c++, vector

I'm basically trying to use vector, but there is a problem with it. By the way, the problem that I'm trying to solve is USACO December 2014 Bronze Problem #4. The code is down below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num,min,max;
    cin>>num>>min>>max;

    vector <pair<int,int> > cow;

    for(int a=0;a<num;num++)
    {
        int temp;
        int temp2;
        cin>>temp>>temp2;

        cow.push_back (temp2);

        if(temp=="NS")
            cow[a].second=0;
        else if(temp=="S")
            cow[a].second=1;
    }

    sort(cow.begin(),cow.end());

    int count=0;

    cout<<"Count="<<count<<endl;

    for(int b=0;b<num;b++)
    {
        cout<<"Weight: "<<cow[b].first;
        if(cow[b].second==0)
            cout<<"Spots: NO"<<endl;
        else if(cow[b].second==1)
            cout<<"Spots: YES"<<endl;
    }
}
```

The expected result should be that the vector should be arranged in numerical order, but I'm stuck at the first step. Also, the error it gives me says: No matching member function for call to 'push_back'

I don't know how to deal with this, and I also can't find any online resources on a similar problem. Can somebody please help?

*edit: changed int temp to string temp

Comment: `cow` is a `vector <pair<int,int> >` and not a `vector<int>`.

Comment: `cow.push_back (temp2);`? Did you mean `cow.push_back({ temp, temp2 });`? Also, those `if (temp == "NS")` comparisons don't work with an `int` and a string literal.

Comment: I just added the problem reference for people who might want to look at the question and see if it helps any more. To be honest, rather than it being a problem with creating an algorithm, it's a far more basic problem for creating and inputing values into a vector so I don't think it really matters.

Comment: It won't be obvious why until you understand types, but [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) (and [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back)) is an online resource which pretty comprehensively answers your question.  Also [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair).

Answer (score 2):

You declared a vector of pairs but are pushing back into the vector an int

Comment: `
vector <pair<int,int> > cow;

    for(int a=0;a<num;num++)
    {
        string temp;
        int temp2;
        cin>>temp>>temp2;

        cow.push_back (temp2,0);

        if(temp=="NS")
            cow[a].second=0;
        else if(temp=="S")
            cow[a].second=1;
    }
`
This is the change that I made but it produces the same error.

Comment: @SeanKim, sending two separate integers won't work. You need to create a `pair<int, int>` object to send to push_back. `cow.push_back( {temp2, 0} );`

Comment: @brady in that case, how will i be able to input values for the `pair<int,int>` object?

Comment: @SeanKim Determine the second element before you `push_back`, not after.